# Change ActionBar content padding through styles

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, android-styles

I've been reading about this and found out that it came with the SDK 24 and already found the solution to Toolbar extra margin/padding, just set: `app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"`

The problem is, most of my activities layouts doesn't theme "no action bar", example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="package">
        <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listViewContato" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So in this case, how the hell can i remove the extra margin/padding? Because it would be annoying change all activities to add the toolbar...

Comment: If you want make `actionBar` customized, you need to use Toolbar. Also it is easy to use with `<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>`.

Comment: Use a Toolbar, then specify its custom layout. See Google's official documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html